# Find pattern in two numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

If I'm given two sets of numbers, how can I find out what the fixed amount fee is and what's the variable?  Example

\$100 - taxes and fees (\$19.7 or 19.7%) = \$119.7

\$200 - taxes and fees (\$33.7 or 16.85%) = \$233.7

The formula is

(Price + Fee)*Tax

I'm trying to solve for Fee and tax

Comment: Do you mean $100 **plus** taxes and fees? And the same thing for $200?

Comment: So net cost is $100 and $200 and then there's a fixed fee added and on top of all of that you then add tax.  i only have those 4 numbers and am trying to figure out how to break out what the fee and tax is (which is consistent in both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be the fee and $t$ be the tax.  I believe your formula should be the final price is (Price+Fee)(1+tax).  Just multiplying by the tax rate gives you the tax, but not the final cost.  Plug in your data and you have two equations in two unknowns
$$(100+f)(1+t)=119.7\\(200+f)(1+t)=233.7\\
f+100t+ft=19.7\\f+200t+ft=33.7\\
100t=14\\t=0.14\\100+f=\frac {119.7}{1.14}=105\\
f=5$$
where the fifth line comes from subtracting the two above.

Comment: thank you!  much appreciated, i should have known this...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using a system of two equations with two unknowns fee $f$ and tax $t-1$:
$$
\begin{cases}
(100 + f) t = 119.7 \\
(200 + f) t = 233.7 
\end{cases} 
$$

Can you take it from here or do you need more help?

Comment: thank you, much appreciated